# 3D logarithmic spiral using Fibonacci sequence

Tags: 3d, fibonacci-numbers

I would like to get an equation of a 3D logarithmic spiral using the Fibonacci sequence so I can  use it in GeoGebra. I'm an artist, not a mathematician. This is beyond my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want something that's got a surface, like a nautilus shell, or something that's linear, like a helix?

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/v4nqfzu9 - see more info about the parametric equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral)

Comment: Hi Brian! Both would be great (helix and surface). This link geogebra.org/calculator/v4nqfzu9 is not in 3D

Comment: You can make it 3D by adding another argument to `Curve`, e.g. `Curve(a*e^(k*t)*cos(t), b*e^(k*t)*sin(t), t/10, t, min, max)`